# Rdbms one way sync with Realm Object Server possible?

Tags: mobile, realm

I'm looking into Realm Mobile Database and Realm Mobile Platform to implement an offline first mobile app. I think my scenario is pretty common:

I've a website with a SQL database, I need a mobile app to display the data from the website, read only data. This app will be eventually connected so I need to sync the data from server to client when the client get connected, and then consume that data offline.

I need to know if anyone is doing something like an ETL to keep a SQL DB synched with Realm Object Server in order to sync it with the mobile clients.

Just one way SQL -> Realm Object Server -> Realm Mobile Database.

I'm just discovering Realm so I want to know if this is doable?

Comment: Yes , I also want to know exactly this, I think.  (In my case I in fact want the sync to happen **both ways**; from the apps, all the way through to the actual SQL server.)   Say HCentelles - in my case the actual database is AmaazonRDS.  For clarity when you say "sql database", what is it in your case?  Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible, but not in the freely available version of the Realm Mobile Platform on the Realm Website.

At the moment, only a sync-enabled version of the Realm Node.JS SDK is capable of opening and writing data to synchronized Realm files located on the server. This SDK is only presently available to people who have purchased the Enterprise edition of the Realm Mobile Platform. The developer edition of the Realm Mobile Platform only allows for modification of synchronized Realms from a user's local device.

A version of the Realm Mobile Platform with server-side integrations intended for indie level developers is also on its way. :)

Comment: Make sense @TiM. So using that enterprise SDK do you think I'll be able to keep synced a DB with around a 1M rows/docs and an write rate in the order of tens of Tx/s at peaks?

Comment: Thanks @hcentelles! I believe so! It obviously depends on the complexity, but data is transmitted in a compressed state, with only deltas sent after the fact, so a million rows of data shouldn't be a problem. Um, I'm not sure what you mean by 'tens of Tx/s', but it can handle very high amounts of traffic. Please feel free to send an email to `info@realm.io` if you'd like to ask more. :)

Comment: thanks @TiM. I mean writes per second in the double digits order.

Comment: HI @TiM - sorry to spam your comments.  Look: is there some confusion here. Let's say that we certainly have the enterprise edition as a baseline, so forget that issue.  Let's say we have "AAA" being iphone/androids.  Let's say we have "BBB" being Realm's epic RealmObjectServer (to be specific, let's say it's a RealmObjectServer literally running on an Amazon EC2 Ubunto 16.04 instance, installed using your natty AMI). So that's "BBB".  Now let's say "CCC" is my teams traditional website which is an Amazon RDS, fairly relational sql database, and then of course the Falcon/java/etc web for that.

Comment: SO !!  AAA is the phones.  BBB is the epic R.O.S. (actually an EC2).  CCC is a good old fashioned, somewhat relational, SQL database (actually an AmazonRDS - but obviously any SQL database).  So!  Of course, AAA and BBB sync perfectly. Deletes!  Updates!   In tunnels!  Offline, online!  The miracle of Realm.  **BUT** ................ how can we sync BBB to CCC, @TiM?  Can you help me understand?  (My confusion here is, in this answer above you appear to be saying "Yes, AAA syncs BBB" ....... but what about BBB syncs CCC?)  Thanks mate!

Comment: (i'm not tim) The enterprise edition has a NodeJS SDK which is able to listen to changes in the ROS, and react accordingly. Obviously there is no automatic way to listen to changes in the SQL DB unless you specifically use the NodeJS SDK to forward any change made in the SQLDB to the ROS to portray said change. I haven't actually seen the data connector API, so I don't know if there is a more automatic way of doing that.

Comment: Haha thanks for the comments Joe Blow! Right, something I should have made more clear here is that the ROS version of the Realm Node.js SDK comes with a special feature called the Event Listener. This lets you register a callback function in your Node.js code that lives in a separate process to ROS, and will be triggered each time Realm detects a change has occurred on a device. (I'm actually doing a presentation on this at a Realm meet-up next week!)

Comment: So in this way, it's pretty straightforward to have 2-way communication between ROS and a third party database. You can be alerted when data for a user in Realm changes, and you can then bridge this to your backend RDS via the Node.js SDK. Conversely, when your RDS performs a change, you can forward this back to Realm. Any write transactions performed in the ROS Node.js SDK are then automatically synchronized with the relevant user devices.

Comment: hey @TiM - fascinating; I'll get in to that and check it out.  Awesome.  Just BTW, on this lame-ass SO site, it's worthwhile "notifying" the other person, you go snail-symbol then nickname.  (I only saw your very valuable messages just now!)

Comment: hey @TiM - to save me typing, what is the URL for the documentation for this awesome "Event Listener" concept ?  thanks!

Comment: Hey Joe! Wait, really? I didn't know it actually did that. What about names with spaces though? Does @Joe Blow trigger it? I always assumed if you'd contributed to a message thread, you'll be notified of any messages after that. We're putting together a large set of tutorials for both iOS and Android outlining the event handling feature right now (As in, literally as I'm writing this!). Keep an eye on the Realm website this coming Monday. :D (Also, thanks so much for the bounty!)

Comment: right, their system is dumb - bottom line it's best to do the ampersand-name. (Example, i was NOT notified about your earlier comments.)  regarding the space I have never figured that out!  Note that there is an AUTOFILL, go snail, j, o and you'll see a button top left of this field. that seems to be the deal.  All understood thanks